# Optimal control of Euler equations of gas dynamics in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the optimal control for the Euler equations of gas dynamics with the cost functional of the tracking type function. The idea is optimal solutions must match the target solutions at a final time by updating the control function using the steepest descent method. I have done the program using Matlab, but the result doesn't achieve the goal; I have attached the part of the code where the issue is. The problem is mainly with the optimization loop. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

```
 alphaAD0 = 2.9*[1,1,1];  % optim step for adjoint
   
ObjwAD = costfunction(rho,m,E,rhod,md,Ed,par);

  for iter = 2:maxIter
        alphaAD = alphaAD0;
        
        rhoinv = rhoT(end:-1:1,:);
        minv = mT(end:-1:1,:);
        Einv = ET(end:-1:1,:);


        [p,q] = initbackward(rho,m,E,rhod,md,Ed,par);

   [pp,qq] = backwardsolve(p,q,rhoinv,minv,Einv,par);
  
   [ADgradJrho0,ADgradJm0,ADgradJE0] = qradcost(pp,qq,rho0,m0,E0,par);
     % Update data
        rho00 = rho0 - alphaAD(1)*ADgradJrho0;
        m00 = m0 - alphaAD(2)*ADgradJm0;    
        E00 = E0 - alphaAD(3)*ADgradJE0;

        [rhoT,mT,ET] = forwardsolve(rho00,m00,E00,par);
       
        rho = rhoT(end,:);
        m = mT(end,:);
        E = ET(end,:);
        
   
    u = m./rho;
    p = (par.G - 1)*(E - 0.5*rho.*u.^2);
        
         Objfunc_1 = ObjwAD(iter-1);
        Objfunc = costfunction(rho,m,E,rhod,md,Ed,par); 
        
        while Objfunc>Objfunc_1 || isnan(Objfunc)
            alphaAD =  alphaAD/2;
            rho00 = rho0 - alphaAD(1)*ADgradJrho0;
            m00 = m0 - alphaAD(2)*ADgradJm0;    
            E00 = E0 - alphaAD(3)*ADgradJE0;

            [rhoT,mT,ET] = forwardsolve(rho00,m00,E00,par);
       
            
            rho = rhoT(end,:);
            m = mT(end,:);
            E = ET(end,:);
            u = m./rho;
    p = (par.G - 1)*(E - 0.5*rho.*u.^2);
            
            Objfunc = costfunction(rho,m,E,rhod,md,Ed,par);
        end
        
        rho0 = rho00; m0 = m00; E0 = E00;
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to reduce the amount of code in this question and rather post only the relevant code together with everything that is needed to execute the code including example data? Also: calling `clear all` in the first line of a function doesn't do anything, because the function workspace is empty whenever the function is called. The `clear all;` in the beginning is just used in scripts rather than functions.